# Bonobo git server integration with Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity, bonobo

I configured Teamcity with my Bonobo git server but I got this error when test it :

> Test connection failed in PartSilicon / Dev List remote refs failed:
>
> cannot locate repository at http://192.168.1.159/Dogharoon.git:
>
> http://192.168.1.159/Dogharoon.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
> not found

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the Bonobo git server on IIS is not configured as Application.

The solution is :

```
Run IIS Manager and navigate to Sites -> Default Web Site.
Right click on Bonobo Git Server and convert to application.
Check if the selected application pool runs on .NET 4.0 and convert the site.
```